# Prepare state $|00\rangle+|1+\rangle$ using Clifford gates and the T-gate

Tags: circuit-construction, clifford-group

I am looking for a quantum circuit which maps state $|00\rangle$ to $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1+\rangle$.

The circuit should only apply quantum gates from the Clifford group (specifically, $CNOT$, $H$, $P$) and the $T$ gate:

$$
CNOT = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & i
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i \pi / 4}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

#### My Thoughts

Because these gates are universal for quantum computation (as stated [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807006)), I know that a circuit which approximates $|\psi\rangle$ must exist. I am hoping that I can produce $|\psi\rangle$ exactly, but I was not able to find the corresponding circuit.

I already figured out the the circuit needs to apply $T$ at least one, as $|\psi\rangle$ has no stabilizers from the Pauli group (determined by brute-force), and any state produced by a Clifford circuit would have stabilizers from the Pauli group.

Comment: Do you allow any gate from the Clifford group or only these specific generators $(CNOT, H, P)$?

Comment: @JSDJ I clarified now that I only want to allow these specific generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circuit is a Hadamard + a Controlled - Hadamard gate.

[image]

Note that $ S $ gate is $ P $ gate in your notation.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! In case you used a specific method for constructing this circuit, adding this to your answer would be very helpful (even a reference would help).

Comment: @Peter I just looked at the definition of Controlled-H gate in Qiskit.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This circuit is also a proof that you *need* two T gates to produce the state you want. Because it makes clear that, given the state, you can apply operations that undo the $\sqrt{X} = HPH$ and the CNOT leaving behind two T states.